# Flask Security- check what Roles a User has

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I was looking at the flask-security api and i dont see any function that returns the list of roles a specific User has. Is there anyway to return a list of Roles a user has?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at how the [`has_role(...)` method](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/core.py#L318) has been defined, it simply iterates through `self.roles`. So the `roles` attribute in the user is a list of `Role` objects.

You need to define your `User` and `Role` models as in the example [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html), so that the `User` model has a many-to-many relationship to `Role` model set in the `User.roles` attribute.

```py
# This one is a list of Role objects
roles = user.roles
# This one is a list of Role names
role_names = (role.name for role in user.roles)
```

Comment: [has_role()](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/674b18103fa8734aca71bbd084ea01e3709817ef/flask_security/core.py#L399)  updated link to the method